# ClickOnce - The .mdf file is reset when publish update

Tags: c#, visual-studio, clickonce

when publish update for my ClickOnce application every thing works fine.
In the application the .mdf and .ldf file are:

status - data files (automatic)

download group - required

hash - include

At start the update installed successfully, but my .mdf database file is reset...
Any suggestion?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using entity framework? If so, you may have left your context in always create mode.

Comment: i'm not using entity framework. the property of mdf file is Copy if newest

Comment: Better it to store  the .mdf and .ldf file at any other location instead of installation folder, becouse click once is creating new folder on each update.

Comment: when the end user start application check update, install it but the database mdf is empty. there is a way to continue working on the same database used before the update?